# Apply Membership Services to remote sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I have created a Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET Web Application. I've noticed that if you change the line

```
 <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

to attach a database of your choosing if it hasn't been created yet, membership services will create it for you. For instance if you change "aspnetdb.mdf" to what ever "mynewdb.mdf" when that database file does not exist it will get created and tables etc will be generated.

If I have a remote sql server, all I know is Server Name: ATLAS-SQL-07 and I have the username and password to access the database. How do I then get membership services to auto generate the tables and stored procedures in that database?

Comment: You are going to need to run Aspnet_regsql.exe on THAT server.  And you will need owner permission.  On a local server it may have automated some stuff for you but remote is different.

Comment: I've tried, however simply typing in ATLAS-SQL-07 won't point aspnet_regsql in the right direction

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Your host does not allow remote connection; however, you can build the db locally and import it using their admin portal. I posted links containing that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the tutorial [creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) found on asp.net.

Note: in this tutorial when it asks for the server you give it the fully qualified web path for your server. This information should be provided in your hosting account web portal.

This quote from [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) may also give you more insight into what you are wanting to do.

> The ASP.NET SQL Server Registration tool is used to create a Microsoft
>   SQL Server database for use by the SQL Server providers in ASP.NET, or
>   to add or remove options from an existing database. The
>   Aspnet_regsql.exe file is located in the
>   [drive:]\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version folder on your Web
>   server.
>
> You can run Aspnet_regsql.exe without any command-line arguments to
>   run a wizard that will walk you through specifying connection
>   information for your SQL Server installation, and installing or
>   removing the database elements for the membership, role management,
>   profile, Web Parts personalization, and health monitoring features.

It seems that your host does not allow remote connection. http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Hosting/Databases/how-do-i-connect-remotely-to-my-database-778/

However, after further research you should be able to import the database in. Therefore, you can create the databse properly locally and import everything use the interface provided by your host. http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Databases/Windows-MSSQL/how-do-i-import-export-a-mssql-database-793/

Comment: I know how to apply Membership schema to localhost databases, but I don't think you've understood my question, its not to be applied to localhost database, its to be applied to a remote host

Comment: I used this same tutorial a couple years ago to set up the same thing on my hosts server. It gives you all the information you need.

Comment: Yeah, still all I have is the sql server name . . .

Comment: You have access to the hosting account web portal correct? In the web portal, most likely in the database section, you should see the fully qualified path for your server along with the login requirements.

Comment: Nope, all I'm given is Server Name:ATLAS-SQL-07, Uid, Pwd

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12884/discussion-between-josh-mein-and-no1-melman)